# Automatically move through anchors

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, anchor

I need a way to automatically/programmatically move through anchors on the homepage of a [WordPress site](http://www.troybouman.com/apd/). The anchor's I want to move through are the tabs in the middle.

For example: page loads, waits specified time, tab 2 opens, waits specified time, tab 3 opens, waits specified time, tab 4 opens, and then keeps repeating. Once it gets to the end, I want it to go back to the beginning. Ideally it would stop on hover if mouse, but I haven't tried to implement that yet.

I have tried to create a JavaScript program in the "text" part of the post showing on the homepage, but it doesn't seem to work. I see the `"Test"` alert, but never see the `"Hello"` alert.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function scrollTo(hash) {
    location.hash = "#" + hash;
    alert('Hello');
}
function tabSlider() {
    delay = 2000; //2 second delay
    setTimeout(function() {scrollTo(ert_pane1-1);},delay);
    setTimeout(function() {scrollTo(ert_pane1-2);},delay*2);
    setTimeout(function() {scrollTo(ert_pane1-3);},delay*3);
    setTimeout(function() {scrollTo(ert_pane1-4);},delay*4);
    setTimeout(function() {scrollTo(ert_pane1-0);},delay*5);
    tabSlider();
    alert('Test');
}
window.onload = tabSlider();
//-->
</script>
```

The plugin for the tabs is [Easy Responsive Tabs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-responsive-tabs/).

Thanks to brasofilo, here is the final working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function scrollTo(hash) {
    location.hash = "#" + hash;
    jQuery( "a[href='#" + hash + "']" ).click(); // finds <a> with href==hash and clicks
}
function tabSlider() {
    delay = 3000; //2 second delay
    setTimeout(function() {scrollTo('ert_pane1-1');},delay);
    setTimeout(function() {scrollTo('ert_pane1-2');},delay*2);
    setTimeout(function() {scrollTo('ert_pane1-3');},delay*3);
    setTimeout(function() {scrollTo('ert_pane1-4');},delay*4);
    setTimeout(function() { scrollTo('ert_pane1-0'); tabSlider(); }, delay*5 );
}
window.onload = tabSlider();
//-->
</script>
```

**EDIT** For those who want to know how I did my hover, I just used jQuery to prevent the click:

```
var hovering = 0;
jQuery ("#primary").hover(function() { hovering = 1; },
                  function() { hovering = 0; });
function scrollTo(hash) {
    if (hovering==1) {
    //Do nothing
    } else {
    location.hash = "#" + hash;
    jQuery( "a[href='#" + hash + "']" ).click(); // finds <a> with href==hash and clicks
    }
}
```

Comment: [sidenote] your `Turbo-Background_web-edited-2_edited-1.png` has a whooping 5.6MB, that can go down to KBs easily...

Comment: Thanks for the note. I haven't optimized the images yet. I appreciate you taking the time to mention it though!

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get tabSlider to stop on hover of the mouse?? Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to clear the timeout(s) like shown in the [JavaScript Content box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! For my use I actually just used jQuery to prevent the click if the mousing was hovering. I added the code to the bottom of the question for those who are also wondering. Thanks again brasofilo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `location.hash` will only add the hash to the URL, it doesn't actually navigates to the hash.

As you're already loading jQuery on the site, it's just a matter of forcing a click on the anchor:

```
function scrollTo(hash) {
    location.hash = "#" + hash;
    jQuery( "a[href='#" + hash + "']" ).click(); // finds <a> with href==hash and clicks
}
```

Your `tabSlider` function has two problems:

- `scrollTo(value)` needs to send a string, you're sending an inexistant "variable".
  If you had `var ert_pane1 = 'hash-value';`, then `scrollTo(ert_pane1)` would work.
  As that's not the case you need: `scrollTo('ert_pane1')`.
- the next call to `tabSlider()` has to be inside the last timeout, this way it produces the desired loop.

```javascript
function tabSlider() {
    delay = 2000;
    setTimeout(function() { scrollTo('ert_pane1-1'); }, delay );
    setTimeout(function() { scrollTo('ert_pane1-2'); }, delay*2 );
    setTimeout(function() { scrollTo('ert_pane1-3'); }, delay*3 );
    setTimeout(function() { scrollTo('ert_pane1-4'); }, delay*4 );
    setTimeout(function() { scrollTo('ert_pane1-0'); tabSlider(); }, delay*5 );
}
tabSlider();
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, I tested the code directly on your page with Chrome Dev Tools :)